# Key feature tracking in Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, keypoint

How can I set my own custom feature points for tracking specific objects in video using OpenCV (Python)? 
So far I can find only face feature detection models, which are not customizable. 
Thank you

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196889/opencv-object-tracking-using-feature-detection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opencv - object tracking using feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196889/opencv-object-tracking-using-feature-detection)